# How to use the trained model in meta learning

Tags: deep-learning, meta-learning

I have trained a meta learning model using learn2learn in python. I train the model using 5 way 5 shot. After training, can I use the model to classify a 395 class dataset?

I train the model using 5 way 5 shot. But I think the result can only use to classify 5 class in a 395 class dataset. Please correct me if I am wrong.